# How to pass values between routes in express without using query params or global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Backgroud :-

- I have a app.post route to which data is coming from HTML page.
- `I want to pass contents req.body to app.get route without using query params or global variable.`
- **query params will expose imp details and the global variable will   not work if simultaneous user uses the application.**

  ```
   app.post('/tester', (req, res) => {
       console.log(req.body.var1)
      res.redirect('/Dashboard');        

      });
  ```

I want to pass this value to Dashboard route.

```
app.get('/Dashboard', (req, res) => {
         //sone DB operation with values form post route and then display it dynamically 
            res.render('employeeDashboard',{employeeName:employeeFirstName})
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: You seem to have 2 options. You will need to store your body per user in a file or database. Or you can use express-session to store body per each user using cookies. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: Anything works, which is fast and easier to implement, do you have an example code for both?

Comment: Session storage is cheaper and faster related to database or file system operations. @Quentin's answer is pretty enough for you. You can check the express-session module's example codes or you can google express-session usage. There're plenty of examples.

Comment: I will look into it.

Comment: I checkupon theprovided link, and i saw this `app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))`

As you might have observed in the question, app.post will get different data from multiple users, i cannot hardcode `secret` value as shown in the example.
i need to use app.post received data which will be different and store dynamically for each request.
does this modules allows that to store secret dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard mechanism for sharing user-specific data across requests without exposing that data to the user is sessions.

The data is associated with a unique token on the server, then the token is set to the client and stored in a cookie. The client will send it back to the server on subsequent requests and the data can be retrieved from the server-side store by looking it up by the token value.

The usual way to handle this on Express is via the [express-session module](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html).

A variant of the technique which erases the data after it has been used once (so you can use it for a single redirect without it persisting beyond that) is called *flash* and implemented on top of sessions. The [express-flash module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash) provides this functionality.

Comment: Thank you quentin.Do you have an example code for reference?

Comment: I checkupon your provided link, and i saw this `app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))`

As you might have observed in the question, app.post will get different data from multiple users, i cannot hardcode `secret` calue as shows in the example.
i need to app.post received data which will be different and store dynamically for each request.
does this modules allows that to store secret dynamically?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra — The secret is used to sign the session data for security purposes. It is not the data that you want to store. It does not need to be unique per user. You can hard code the secret.

Comment: @thanks Quentin for the explanation.i will try implementing it. Will post another question if there any issues.